# Include jslink in newform when a list is saved as template

Tags: jslink, list-template, newform

I have created a list and in the newform I have added a jslink in it. Then I have saved this list as a List template to create other lists based on it.

When I create a new list based on this list template above, the jslink is not added anymore in the newform.

How can I add the jslink in the newform of the List Template I saved?

Answer (score 0):

Alas The JSLink is not part of the Template as the Template can be used on another Site Collection and existing JSLinks *may* point to non-existing files.

(*you could also say: Microsoft did not update the old Template code to include JSLinks .. then again Publishing Sites can't be templated because of hardcoded ContentType IDs*)

#### So you have to re-assign the JSLinks again, by hand, or with code

### https://icsr.github.io/JSLinkManager.html

Makes the manual way a bit easier:

[image]